# How to know if its zoom in or zoom out on flex/air TransformGestureEvent

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

Using flex / air 2.6 working on an Android device, I am using a canvas with a TransformGestureEvent for zoom in on a map. The listening of the efect is working ok, but I can´t seem to find the information on wether the user intended zoom in or zoom out (fingers getting closer or getting apart).

I expected the intention of the gesture to be identifiable with the offsetX and offsetY properties of the event, as you will do on a swipe gesture event. But I always get 0 for both properties, no matter how I do the gesture in the device.

How can I know if the fingers getting closer or getting apart in a gesture zoom event?

Thanks

Maria

Comment: Found the answer here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3pinchzoom    The event shows if its zoom in or zoom out and the extent of it in the properties scaleX and scaleY

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you using Canvas for a mobile app?  It's deprecated and you should use something like Group.

Second, you should [look at the API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3agestureZoom).  There's a very good example showing what you're trying to do.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    [SWF(width=320, height=460, frameRate=24, backgroundColor=0x000000)]
    public class TransformGestureExample2 extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="african_elephant.jpg")]
        public var ElephantImage:Class;
        public var scaleDebug:TextField;
        public var rotateDebug:TextField;

        public function TransformGestureExample2()
        {
            // Debug
            var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            tf.color = 0xffffff;
            tf.font = "Helvetica";
            tf.size = 11;
            this.scaleDebug = new TextField();
            this.scaleDebug.width = 310;
            this.scaleDebug.defaultTextFormat = tf;
            this.scaleDebug.x = 2;
            this.scaleDebug.y = 2;
            this.stage.addChild(this.scaleDebug);
            this.rotateDebug = new TextField();
            this.rotateDebug.width = 310;
            this.rotateDebug.defaultTextFormat = tf;
            this.rotateDebug.x = 2;
            this.rotateDebug.y = 15;
            this.stage.addChild(this.rotateDebug);

            var elephantBitmap:Bitmap = new ElephantImage();
            var elephant:Sprite = new Sprite();

            elephant.addChild(elephantBitmap);

            elephant.x = 160;
            elephant.y = 230;

            elephantBitmap.x = (300 - (elephantBitmap.bitmapData.width / 2)) * -1;
            elephantBitmap.y = (400 - (elephantBitmap.bitmapData.height / 2)) *-1;

            this.addChild(elephant);

            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
            elephant.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
            elephant.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, onRotate);
        }

        private function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
        {
            this.scaleDebug.text = (e.scaleX + ", " + e.scaleY);
            var elephant:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
            elephant.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
            elephant.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
        }

        private function onRotate(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
        {
            var elephant:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
            this.rotateDebug.text = String(e.rotation);
            elephant.rotation += e.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```